# How to ensure Ubuntu Workspaces maintain shape after restart?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

## Overview:

I'm a life-time Windows user & in windows 10 & 11 there is a feature where you can create multiple Desktops. Which basically allows me to like divide my attention, So I usually have one for work, other for Study, etc.. When I used to restart the system the Desktops would retain. So if I had 3, on restart there would be 3 & If lets say I had 2 Firefox windows 1 in Desktop 1 & other in Desktop 2, When after restart I would open FireFox the FireFox windows would automatically get reorganized into their desktops according to last session.

## Problem:

For almost 3 months I've started using Linux & more accurately Ubuntu Linux. In ubuntu similar feature exists where I can create Workspaces. But unlike Windows the Workspaces don't retain their shape, so, after restarting I have to recreate all the Workspaces & reorganize FireFox Windows.

I wanted to know if there is a way to maintain the workspaces in Ubuntu just like in Windows?

## My Progress so far:

I tried to find the solution by myself but I wasn't able to find any settings or plugins on the Snap Store that would allow me to do so.

So far I haven't been able to find any other tools or scripts that would allow me to do that either.